# Походження фразеологізму "у свинячий голос"

Tags: етимологія, фразеологізми

Інколи говорять *"Прийшов додому у свинячий голос".*

> ["У свинячий голос"](http://svitslova.com/idioms-dictionary/2289-v-svyniachyj-golos.html) - означає дуже пізно.

***Яке походження має фразеологізм "у свинячий голос"? Звідки взявся даний вислів? Можливо є якісь схожі вирази з цим же значенням?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Найпоширеніша версія походження цього фразеолоґізму така:

> Колись давно свиней виганяли пасти. Жадібні свині дуже часто додому
>   поверталися вночі й подавали свинячий голос – рохкали, вищали. Таким
>   чином, люди почали говорити «у свинячий голос», маючи на увазі «дуже
>   пізно».

Джерела: [Мова - ДНК нації.](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/frazeologizmu/u-svunyachuj-golos) [Світ фразеолоґізмів.](http://pidruchniki.com/2015082666418/kulturologiya/poti_chola)

Схожий вираз знаходимо ось [тут](http://rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=24&t=396):

> (несвоєчасно, запізно – з сл. приходити, з’являтися та ін.) у свинячий
>   голос;
>
> (наприкінці, коли всі розходяться) **на шапкобрання**.
>
> До школи учень у свинячий голос приходить (Яновський, 1, 1954; с. 26);
>   Та ми ж пішки поспіємо **на шапкобрання**. Так буде, як у ту неділю:
>   люди з церкви, а ми в церкву (Карпенко-Карий, 1, 1960, с. 398).

Трохи інший, але дотичний вираз є [тут](http://ycilka.net/slovnyk_fraz_view.php?id=16):

> після других півнів - дуже пізно, далеко за північ;